can I use SS316 bush in Aluminum bronze body?
In a recent design, I have considered stainless steel bush and stainless steel block which pivot on bush and expected to mvoe freely. Block's fucntion is to transfer the force and motion through this bush. But after around 2000 cycles of operation, they got locked each other and the block doesn't move or swing freelly any more. Found that the reason could be galling.
Alternatively I am considering Aluminum bronze block to replace stainless steel. So now the combination would be stainless steel bush and Aluminum bronze block. Would it work?

What about any lubrication?

Used molybdinum disulfide/ MOLYKOTE anti friction spray, but not effective

If Al Bronze is okay in the application, why use a SS bushing? Use Bronze bushing.

Aluminum alloys and stainless steel are both corrosion-resistant because of the stable oxide layer that naturally skins them over and protects the base metal from further oxidation.
This layer is thin and can be readily broken by friction in rotary motion. the exposed metal immediately oxidizes; that oxide is frictionally broken, causing more oxidation, and clogging the clearance between the rotating parts with a gummy mix of metal and oxide. This is one form of galling.
This makes both stainless and aluminum alloys unsuitable for rotary contact. I would not recommend using any combination of the two as shaft and bushing.
